# Restarting Service w/ `chkconfig`?

Tags: linux, rhel6, chkconfig

After running:

```
sudo chkconfig --add X
sudo chkconfig X on
```

I ran `chkconfig --list X`:

```
$ chkconfig --list X
X           0:off   1:off   2:on    3:on    4:on    5:on    6:off
```

My understanding is that, after `kill -9`-ing it, the service will restart.

However, after running `kill -9 $PID` where `$PID` is the PID of the service's process, it did not restart.

In other words, running `ps -ef | grep X` returned only the `grep` result.

How can I use `chkconfig` to ensure that, after my service crashes, it will restart?

Comment: What makes you think that your process should magically restart after you kill it?

Comment: Per `step 4`, "Set it to autostart
" in http://www.abhigupta.com/2010/06/how-to-auto-start-services-on-boot-in-centos-redhat/

Comment: Right, autostart **on boot**. That's what chkconfig controls, which processes get started on boot.

Answer (score 3):

That isn't chkconfig's job.. Try [monit](https://mmonit.com/monit/) or the like.

Comment: Thanks. I found this helpful answer too - http://superuser.com/a/687188/151187.

Answer (score 2):

`ckconfig` does not actually stop or start anything. As the manual explains:

> [**chkconfig**](http://linux.die.net/man/8/chkconfig) provides a simple command-line tool for maintaining the `/etc/rc[0-6].d` directory hierarchy by relieving system administrators of the task of directly manipulating the numerous symbolic links in those directories. ...

That's it.

On RHEL 6  [`init`](http://linux.die.net/man/8/init) and Upstart are what actually start and stop certain jobs on boot, shutdown or on changing runlevels according to how that  `/etc/rc[0-6].d` directory hierarchy is set up.

You can use Upstart to control startup of services and restart for if and when they fail by using the `respawn` keyword in an [`init`](http://linux.die.net/man/5/init) conf file.

Answer (score 0):

`/etc/inittab` can be used to force restarting a service if it's using a SystemV style init script, if we're talking RHEL >=6.2 Upstart is available too and you can just add a `respawn` line to the service's definition file in `/etc/init`. See DigitalOcean's [tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-a-linux-service-to-start-automatically-after-a-crash-or-reboot-part-1-practical-examples) for details.

Or think about upgrading/reinstalling to RHEL7.

Systemd supports automatically restarting services on crashes.

Run `systemctl edit foo.service`

```
[Service]
Restart=on-failure
```